# Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick

Tags: excel, vba, double-click

By DoubleClicking anywhere on my worksheet, I run the macro "Activate_Editor" to bring up a UserForm. This works fine, but before the UserForm will work, I must hit the ESCAPE key as the top menu and ribbons are all grayed-out. Is there a work-around for this quirk?

Thank you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
   'Double-Clicking anywhere on Worksheet runs macro
   Activate_Editor
End Sub
```

Comment: Figured it out.... Add the statement "Cancel = True" - Works great!